# Insert text into the input/textarea using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="ctrlHolder">
<label for="" id="name.label">Name</label>
<input name="name" id="name" type="text" class="textInput small" />
<p class="formHint">The name of the item you are submitting</p>
</div>
```

How can I insert predefined text into a input element. I'd like this function to active when the user doubleclicks the label element.

```
$('#name.label').dblclick(function(){
    $('#name').val('some text');
});
```

Comment: I would be cautious to use dots in element identifiers as they may or may not confuse the jQuery selectors: #name.label matches an element that has both id="name" and class="label".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/KBWDy/3/) check this fiddle

you can use [.text("yourPreDefinedText")](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to replace the text of an element

Comment: Thanks for that example. However, I would like to be able to change the value of the input element not the label. When I try it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: When the lable is double clicked, not the input

Comment: It's working well in the example. I can't get it to work on my site here: http://tinyurl.com/6gcwkg2

Comment: to insert inside input :
  $("#inputID").val("theText");

Answer (score 1):

$('#name.label') will cause jQuery to look for an element with id "name" and class "label".  I believe the code above should work if you rename the label's id to something like "name-label".